¿Cómo puedo hacer la FFT de una señal que tengo?
Quiero hacer la FFT de unos datos que tengo. Cargando el paquete scipy, utilizo rfft y rfftfreq, pero a la hora de graficar, no sale lo que debería salir. Mi código es el siguiente:
# Cargar datos del archivo
with open('25HZ.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
t = []
a = []
for i in f:
    columns = i.strip().split('\t')
    if len(columns) >= 2:
        t.append(float(columns[0]))
        a.append(float(columns[1]))
f.close()

#Eliminar duplicados en t y a
t_sin = []
a_sin = []
for i in range(len(t)):
    if t[i] not in t_sin:
        t_sin.append(t[i])
        a_sin.append(a[i])
t_sin=np.array(t_sin)
a_sin=np.array(a_sin)

# Graficar los datos originales
plt.plot(t_sin, a_sin, '.-')
plt.xlabel('Tiempo (s)', fontsize='14')
plt.ylabel('Wavelenght (nm)', fontsize='14')
plt.title('Datos Originales')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

n=len(a_sin) #numero de muestras de la señal
Ts=0.001 #periodo de muestreo
Fs=1/Ts #frecuencia de muestreo

yf = rfft(a_sin,axis=0)
xf = rfftfreq(n, Ts)

# Graficar
plt.plot(xf,np.abs(yf))
plt.xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)', fontsize='14')
plt.ylabel('Amplitud FFT', fontsize='14')
plt.title('Espectro de Frecuencia')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

Lo que hago es cargar unos datos de un archivo .txt, creo unas listas iguales donde he eliminado los datos repetidos debido a que al muestrear la señal, a veces para un mismo tiempo se guardaba el mismo dato. Después utilizo las funciones para hacer la FFT y sus correspondientes frecuencias.




Hola Álvaro, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Cual es exactamente el problema? "no sale lo que debería salir" no nos da mucha información... Sería también muy conveniente que aportaras el archivo de datos, completo o no, con datos reales o enmascarados, pero que permita reproducir el problema que estás encontrando. ¿Tu muestreo de entrada es uniforme en tiempo?

Hola, el muestreo de entrada es uniforme. He adjuntado el archivo que leo. Cuando digo que no sale lo que debería salir, quiero decir que al plotear el modulo de la FFT frente a las frecuencias, no me sale el pico de la frecuencia donde debería, sino en cero y todo lo demás plano.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
